# Сполучник "як" (у значенні "в якості чогось") - чим замінити?

Tags: словосполучення, сполучники

Добрий день! Дуже часто послуговуюся такою конструкцією: *"Предмет А мислиться як предмет Б"*, *"Письменник витлумачує предмет А як..."* і т.д. Наскільки вдало (з погляду збереження змісту) можна замінити оце *"як"* на *"в ролі"*, *"у значенні"* тощо? Які ще є варіанти? Сполуку "в якості" не підтримую -- вважаю її калькою з російського "в качестве".

Answer (score 1):

Заміна "як" на "в ролі" або "у значенні" є адекватним варіантом і зберігає зміст відношення між предметами/поняттями. Також можна використовувати сполучення "значення" (наприклад, "Предмет А має значення предмету Б") або "синонімічно" (наприклад, "Предмет А вживається синонімічно предмету Б").

Інші варіанти залежать від контексту і можуть бути використані у відповідному випадку. Наприклад:

В розумінні - для надання роз'яснень щодо змісту предмету/поняття.
Як - якщо дуже важливо зазначити точне порівняння між двома предметами/поняттями.
Ідентичним з - якщо два предмети/поняття мають абсолютно однакове значення або є тотожними.
Включає в себе - якщо предмет А є більш широким поняттям, яке включає в себе предмет Б.
У будь-якому випадку, вибір конструкції залежить від контексту і мети висловлювання, і не завжди існує один правильний варіант.